# Sklearn's One-Class SVM with separable Nu Parameter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, data-mining

The existing One-Class Classification (OCC) model implementation from Sklearn  (OneClassSVM) has a parameter (Nu) that handles both the upper bound of training errors and the lower bound of support vectors. I have data that has no training error, however, I still want support vectors. Is there any known Python implementation of OneClassSVM that has separable parameters so that I can specify training error and support vectors separately?

Currently, my alternative is to purposely contaminate my one-class data.

Documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html

Alternatively, is there any pure one-class SVM implementation that does not assume an outlier class instance in training?

Answer (score 0):

These are bounds you're talking about so if you take nu = 0.5 the amount of training errors is allowed to lie between 0 and 0.5, as long as at least half of your data can be used as support vectors